# Sinatra with sessions using Rack::Session::Pool

Tags: ruby, rest, session, sinatra, rack

I am having a problem with Sinatra using `Rack::Session::Pool` for storing session information.
What I want to do is to 'post' some data by appending information to the session hash using `'POST /dataset'`, and then retrieve it by using `'GET /dataset'` and returning the content of 'session' hash. When I try to return the value though, the 'session' hash does not contain the :message key

```
require 'sinatra/base'

class Trial < Sinatra::Base
  use Rack::Session::Pool

  post '/dataset' do
    session[:message] = params[:data]
  end

  get '/dataset' do
    session[:message]
  end

end

Trial.run!
```

I know this looks trivial, but still I can't get it to work...

Comment: Are you using something like [shotgun](https://github.com/rtomayko/shotgun) to reload your app between requests?

Comment: No, plain old Sinatra

Comment: How are you testing this? It works ok when I run it.

Comment: I am using rest_client like this: RestClient.post 'http://localhost:4567/dataset', {:data => [1,2,3]} and then: response =  RestClient.get 'http://localhost:4567/dataset', but response object is empty

Comment: I am using Sinatra 1.3.5 if that matters. Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Even though you are using `Rack::Session::Pool` rather than the default cookie based session storage, you still need to use cookies in the requests. The session data is stored in memory on the server, but the session id needs to be passed with each request in a cookie.

```
response1 = RestClient.post 'localhost:4567/dataset', {:data => '123'}

response2 = RestClient.get 'localhost:4567/dataset', :cookies => response1.cookies

puts response2 #=> 123
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to

```
enable :sessions
```

More [info](http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html) about configuration.

Comment: Thank you, but This actually refers to the Cookies. I still cannot solve the example above...